# boost::sandbox::odeint install

Tags: c++, boost, numeric

I would like to use the odeint module from the boost::sandbox but I am not sure how to integrate the sandbox code which I retrieved from svn into my boost install.  I have boost installed to $BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_45_0.  Is it proper to just merge contents of odeint into my boost path which would place the header at $BOOST_ROOT/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp.

Is this the right approach or is there a standard way of getting and installing boost::sandbox code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any "proper" solution, but I can tell you that you should not meet any problems if you just copy `boost/numeric/odeint.hpp` and `boost/numeric/odeint/*.hpp` to that directory since no file will be overwritten (if something fails just remove them and you're done).

For what its worth I did that for boost::process and it worked without any problems.

Comment: It does seem to fit into the Boost directory tree just fine.  I assume that all sandbox libraries are like that since they are intended for future addition to the core boost library.  At least its a header only library so there will never be any run-time issues.  Thanks for the validation.

Comment: most boost libraries are header only (I assume that's because of their heavy use of templates and simplicity).

Comment: While this will work, I don't see this as the right answer. I don't think installed code should be messed with.

Comment: But, as the other commentors have pointed out, the installed code is _not_ being messed with. This code is just being added to the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

boost.odeint is completely header-only. So, you can copy the content of the odeint/boost directory into your $BOOST_ROOT dir, and everything should work. Alternatively, you could add the location of the odient directory to the include flags of your compiler (for example for gcc -Ipath_to_odeint).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The library has been working out well for me so far and I will probably adopt it for my project if a larger scale test works out well.  What is the present development status, I notice that there has not been any SVN activity recently?  Is there a mailing list or discussion thread going anywhere?  I couldn't find a bug tracker with any open tickets, is there anything to watch out for or that I should try to fix?

Comment: I'd say the second option in this answer is the "correct" one, though technically either would work.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we completely redesign the library. The interface will be the same but it will have some additional features (cuda support, support for structs and tuples as state types) and some more steppers (stiff solvers, implicit solvers, etc.). A bug tracker and a separate list does not exist, but you could use boost-users@lists.boost.org for discussion or suggestions.